# React Native Remote Notification without Expo

Tags: react-native, mobile, websocket, push-notification

I am working on building a mobile application. I used react native on the front end. In my application, I wanna send a notification to users. I used native modules so that I had to eject expo. What is the best way to send remote notification without expo?

Answer (score 0):

This library is the most used one for react native push notifications: [React Native Push Notifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification)

This can help you with firebase push notifications: [Firebase cloud messaging](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)